# PHP script hangs up during socket programming

Tags: php, sockets

my simple php script simply hangs up when i see in firebug

```
    <?php
require 'FirePHPCore/fb.php';
ob_start();

session_start();


FB::log('Log message');
//FB::info('Info message');
//FB::warn('Warn message');
//FB::error('Error message');


        FB::info('i m inside');

        $fileCount = $_POST['count'];
        $data = "i-" . $fileCount;

        FB::info('data for server ' . $data);
        $address = '127.0.0.1';
    $port = 5555;
    set_time_limit(0);

    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname('tcp'));
    socket_connect($socket, $address, $port);

        FB::info('socket connect ');

    $len = strlen($data);

    $status = socket_sendto($socket, $data, $len, 0, $address, $port);


        $input = socket_read($socket, 1024);
        echo $input;    

    socket_close($socket);



     FB::log('i m deadout..');
```

What is the reason behind this problem please help?
thanks. The server (java) running on same machine.

I found out this problem when i saw firebug it simply displays loading icon.
And when i remove the socket programming part it works properly.

Answer (score 0):

php socket connections are opened in blocking mode by default and you need to set using socket_set_nonblock. For an example;

```
$this->soc = socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP);
socket_set_nonblock($this->soc);
```

or

```
$socket = socket_create_listen(1223);
socket_set_nonblock($socket);

socket_accept($socket);
```

Comment: the problem was server at the other end was listening but not on 127.0.0.1 but on 0.0.0.0